# Array of Go structs with the same anonymous filed, but different types

Tags: arrays, data-structures, struct, go

If you imagine I have the following declarations:

```
type Car struct {
    Vehicle
    engineType string
}

type Bus struct {
    Vehicle
    public     bool
    engineType string
}

type Bike struct {
    Vehicle
    motorbike bool
}

type Vehicle struct {
    NumberWheels     int
    NumberPassengers int
    Owner            string
}

type Vehicles []Vehicle
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/P6sOojM4ko)

I'm trying to have an array of Vehicles. However this is not possible as they each have a different type ( i.e `Car`, `Bus`, `Bike`, etc...)

```
var myCar = Car{Vehicle{4, 4, "Me"}, "Manual"}
var myBike = Bike{Vehicle{2, 0, "Bob and I"}, false}
var myVehicles = Vehicles{myCar, myBike}
for i := range myVehicles {
    fmt.Println(myVehicles[i])
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/P6sOojM4ko)

How would you achieve something like this. Or am I trying to tackle this problem from the wrong angle. I'm new to Go.

Comment: Go doesn't have inheritance, so approaching a problem in this manner is usually the wrong choice. Also, the reason you can't do this is that there are no generics, and go types are invariant.

Comment: Use interfaces.  can't find it right now,but there are multiple duplicates of this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Vehicle` is embedded in `Car` and `Bus` so you got things going in the wrong direction... It's not like `Vehicle` is a parent class so you can't get the polymorphic behavior you're looking for out of this design. What you need is an interface.

To show you a working example I'm just going to use empty interface (it will allow you to store any type in the collection). For your actual program you might want to make something like an `IVehicle` interface and put whatever common method all the vehicles will have on it, maybe something like `Start()` or whatever...

https://play.golang.org/p/iPJbFYlo7o

To expand on that embedding thing a little bit... This isn't inheritance. You can accomplish the same things with it however the statement "Car *is a* Vehicle" is not true. This is actually more like composition, "Car has a Vehicle". It's just that `Vehicle`'s fields and methods are 'hoisted' up to `Car`, meaning they can be accessed from an instance of `Car` without another layer of indirection like `Car.Vehicle.FieldOnVehicle`. That's not really what you're looking for. If you want to say "Car is a Vehicle" and it be true, then `Vehicle` needs to be an interface which `Car` implements.

Comment: Well, Vehicle can be a type.  But he *also* needs an interface with methods that all vehicles can do, like start, move, shutdown, etc...  That would allow him to embed Vehicle in his other types and store them together in an array of types that implement IVehicle or whatever, right?

Comment: @saarrrr yeah, sorry if that was unclear. I used `IVehicle` in the second paragraph because that would be the sensible choice assuming he keeps the `Vehicle` type. In the last paragraph I'm talking about his current implementation and just trying to give some broader conceptual information about embedding. The "is a", "has a" crap is the way I remember academics explaining it ;)

Comment: That's what I thought, just making sure my own understand wasn't whacked to all hell.  Thanks, great answer.

Comment: Not sure if in needs a follow up question
but how could you ensurer the data structure is correctly encoded as JSON  https://play.golang.org/p/W0luNEuZ40